# python 3.5 selecting and using results from postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql-9.4

I need to write a program which can,firstly, for ip adresses of people who saw my campaign on google, and then give me detailed information about each of these persons.

I have all information in postgres database and use python 3.5

Here is my code:

```
def get_connection(cursor_factory=None):
    conn_string_pg = "host= '" + host + "' dbname = '" + dbname + "' user = '" + user + \
                 "' password = '" + password + "'"
    if cursor_factory is None:
        conn_pg = psycopg2.connect(conn_string_pg)
    else:
        conn_pg = psycopg2.connect(conn_string_pg, 
        cursor_factory=cursor_factory)
    return conn_pg



def find_logs():

    select = """ select ip_address from log_files o where o.url like 
    '%my_campaign'  
    """
    conn = get_connection(cursor_factory = RealDictCursor)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(select)
    records = cur.fetchone()
    for item in records:
        select_2 = "select * from log_files where ip_address = %(item)s "
        cur.execute(select_2)
        logs = cur.fetchone()
        return logs

print(find_logs())
cur.close()
```

Unfortunately I get this  error:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%" LINE 1:
>   ...elect * from web_logs.log_data where ip_address = %(item)s o...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string interpolation is incorrect. You're trying to insert the value of item into your `select_2` statement, but you don't actually do the string interpolation, so you pass psycopg2 an invalid SQL statement. You want to do something like

```
 select_2 = "select * from log_files where ip_address = {}".format(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ip_address = %(item)s` it's not a valid sql syntax. You should make string formatting before:

```
select_2 = "select * from log_files where ip_address = %(item)s " % {'item': item}
```

And the better way to do it is to give all the transformation to the postgres driver

```
select_2 = "select * from log_files where ip_address = %s "
cur.execute(select_2, (item, ))
```

Comment: thank Oleksandr for the quick reply. the second solution very well, but with cur.execute(select_2, item['ip_address']) i received an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers